# How do I upload a file/directory to a folder within a bucket?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I'm able to upload files or directories to a bucket with the AWS .NET SDK, but they always end up in the root folder.

Is there a way to upload a file to an existing directory?

- edit.  More info:

So I'm using a TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest to upload a directory from my local disk to S3.  I would like the files to be uploaded to a folder in the bucket with the same name as the folder I've selected.

For example.  if I choose the directory c:/stuff to be upload, I want the contents of c:/stuff to go in BucketName/stuff, not directly into the bucket.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do, if not I'll try to provide more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The newest version of the AWS SDK for .NET allows you to set the **KeyPrefix** property on the **UploadDirectoryRequest** (more info [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html)).

Comment: Perfect!  The version I have didn't have that option.

Answer (score 7):

It seems after googling around, you specify a key.  It took me a while, but I believe the key is something like this example:

```
string key = string.Format("{0}/{1}", folder, filename); 
PutObjectRequest rq = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    AutoCloseStream = false,
    BucketName = s3BucketName,
    InputStream = stream,
    Key = key
};

S3ClientInstance.PutObject(rq).Dispose();
```

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping for something that would work for a directory and not by individual file.  The TransferUtilityUploadRequest has a Key as well, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set a common key for a directory upload.  

Thanks for your input.